# cómo puedo agregar jsbarcode a un jspdf

Tags: jquery, java-swing, java-ee, jspdf

¿Cómo puedo agregar un código de barra generado con jsBarcode a un pdf generado con jsPDF? No logro hacerlo, ayuda por favor.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/JsBarcode.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            JsBarcode("#barcode1", "holafunciono123", {
                format: "code39",
                displayValue: true,
                fontSize: 20
            });
        });
        function genPDF() {
            var doc = new jsPDF("landscape", "mm", "a4");
            doc.setFontSize(22);
            doc.text(20, 20, 'Titulo');
            doc.text(100, 20, 'Cupon de descuento');
            doc.text(30, 30, 'MISOFERTAS.COM');
            window.open(doc.output('bloburl'), '_blank');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="myid" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
        <img id="barcode1" />
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:genPDF()">Genera pdf</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola hace días pregunte lo mismo y no me respondieron, pero encontré la solución, lo que genera el JsBarcode es una imagen, por eso lo pones en una etiquetas con un id, y te aparece en el navegador el código de barras, así que lo que debes hacer es convertir esa imagen a base64, y ese código en base 64 es lo que puedes insertar en el pdf que generas; en el pdf se verá como una imagen, saludos.

Comment: Sí, logré hacerlo, pero me di cuenta que no me servía para mis fines, así que use jasper report para hacer un informe más personalizado, de todas formas, gracias por la respuesta, bro!